# How we embed google analytics with angular 4?

Tags: angular, google-analytics-api

Follow questions are already answer on stackoverflow, i can't embed google analytics api on my website using angular 4. Please help me any solutions to embed it. If you have any example , please send it to me, i'm very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use [angulartics](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2).

It's a very powerful package for handling analytics for Angular applications and it [supports Google Analytics](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/tree/master/src/lib/providers/ga) as well.